# Download a Maven artifact and install into a specific local repository (not .m2)

Tags: java, maven

I have several local Maven repositories besides the one located in ~/.m2 directory and I want to simplify the process of installing new artifacts into them from Maven central.

So far I couldn't find a way to tell `mvn dependency:get` that dependency should be put into a specific local repository.
I did manage to find a way to install a given downloaded artifact using `mvn install:install-file -DlocalRepositoryPath=`, but I want to be able to get and put dependencies into a specific repository with as few manual steps as possible.

Before you ask why can't I just configure my project to use Maven central directly here is the answer: the project uses Gradle and I do not own its build script (i.e. I can't modify it). The project build script is written to work with several distinct repositories having the same base URI that I fortunately can change using build.properties file. So my idea is to have several local maven repositories in the same root directory and trick the build script to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `maven.repo.local` property:

```
mvn dependency:get -Dmaven.repo.local=/path/to/localrepo
```